# Adding records with many to many back-references in Go Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

What is the approach in Go Gorm for writing and updating records that are back-referencing many to many structs.

For example, I have a Contact struct with a self-referenced Related property:

```
type Contact struct {
    gorm.Model

    FirstName  string      `json:"first_name"`
    LastName   string      `json:"last_name"`
    MiddleName string      `json:"middle_name,omitempty"`
    Related    []Contact   `json:"related,omitempty" gorm:"many2many:related_contacts"`
}
```

Populating two contacts where each references the other

```
fred := model.Contact{
    FirstName:  "Fred",
    LastName:   "Jones",
    MiddleName: "B",
}

bill := model.Contact{
    FirstName:  "Bill",
    LastName:   "Brown",
    MiddleName: "R",
}

fred.Related = []model.Contact{bill}
bill.Related = []model.Contact{fred}
```

Performing a `db.Save(&fred)` will write two records to the database; one for bill and one for fred, however, bill record doesn't have a back reference to fred (as it hasn't been added yet and has no ID).

If I also perform `db.Save(&bill)`, I now get 4 records, because saving bill didn't know that fred was already saved.

While I do realize that I can save one, then find the second and update it, I am wondering if there is a better "Gorm Way" of doing it where I don't have to manually keep the back references in sync when adding records?

Also, what is the approach if fred is to be removed?    Do I need to take care of the related_contacts table manually?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think you're having is that the `fred` that you have in `bill.Related` is a copy, and thus does not get its ID updated by the call to `db.Save(&fred)`.

When you call `Save` gorm checks the ID field of any models to know whether it should create or update that model.

What I would try is:

```golang
fred := model.Contact{
    FirstName:  "Fred",
    LastName:   "Jones",
    MiddleName: "B",
}
db.Save(&fred)

bill := model.Contact{
    FirstName:  "Bill",
    LastName:   "Brown",
    MiddleName: "R",
    Related:    []model.Contact{fred},
}
db.Save(&bill)

// Now both bill and fred have IDs
fred.Related = []model.Contact{bill}
db.Save(&fred)
```

One thing to watch out for here will be whether gorm tries to save `fred.Related[0]` and goes into an infinite loop. You can manage this by [skipping the upserting of associations](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Skip-Auto-Create-Update). So that means you would change the last two lines to:

```golang
fred.Related = []model.Contact{bill}
db.Omit("Related.*").Save(&fred)


// or using association mode
db.Model(&fred).Association("Related").Append(&bill)
```

EDIT: And with regards to deletion. Knowing nothing about which database you're using, you would normally have to manage related-entity deletion yourself. If you're using a db that supports foreign key constraints you could declare the join table foreign keys as `REFERENCES contacts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. This would mean that if you delete any `Contact`, the rows in the join table that contain the same ID would be automatically deleted also.

Comment: The problem with doing a save for every struct within the model is the amount of back and forth that occurs.   I was trying to do this with a single save on a top level document object and let Gorm figure it out.   Through extensive testing, It doesn't seem to be intelligent enough to understand dependencies between structs.  This is particularly evident if you turn on PRAGMA foreign_keys=on and you can see the insert order is not respected according to foreign key relationships.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the `REFERENCES contacts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE` also doesn't work because of this same issue.   With a complex model, Gorm doesn't recognize the order of deletes and tries to issue a delete on a parent table before deleting a child and the constraint fails...when deleting the top element of a model.

Comment: Have you tried using pointers to models instead of values? Like `Related []*Contact`. This would potentially let you use what you proposed first, but because the related structs aren't copies, but the same bit of memory, their IDs would be populated, so you should end up with just two rows in your `contacts` table and two rows in your join table.

Comment: Also, check this out https://gorm.io/docs/session.html#FullSaveAssociations

Comment: The problem isn't with how Gorm handles the pointer references.   It is actually how it handles nested (cascaded) references.   It doesn't look deep enough and cross object.  It assumes that the dependency is always parent to child, not sibling nor child to cousin.   --- At least from what I have been able to discover.